# How to reliably mount a NTFS volume with read/write access

Tags: permissions, directory, ntfs, awesome

This is a dual-boot Windows/Ubuntu system. I created a link to my Windows Documents folder in my linux home folder so that all my files are easily accessible in both systems, saving duplication. However, there's a lock on the folder icon (see image).

[image: Locked folder]

And I can't create new folders or save anything in there. My guess is that the OS is mounting the volume as read-only. I checked the `/etc/fstab` file to see if I could change it, but there's no mention of any NTFS volumes. So maybe they're getting auto-detected at boot?

This is where the drive is mounted, in `/media/username`:

```
drwxrwxrwx  1 paul paul  8192 Aug 15 18:24 'System SSD'
```

And that points to `/dev/nvme0n1p3`:

```
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 259, 3 Aug 15 20:00 nvme0n1p3
```

`nvme0n1p3` shows in orange, if that matters.

I've done some googling, and tried a bunch of options (including off this site), but none have worked (yet). Two have crashed my system during boot, rendering it unresponsive, with an error telling me about an invalid driver.

For the record, Windows Fast Boot is disabled.

If someone can help me out with a reliable fstab entry that would let me permanently mount the Windows system drive at Linux start-up with read/write access, that would be totally wicked awesome cool.

Comment: Silly question, but when you're moving from Windows to Ubuntu, are you choosing "Restart" to reboot or are you turning the machine off, then starting it up again? There is a difference between the two, as Windows will not release its hold on some devices until the machine is *off* off ... 

Comment: Not a silly question...  I've tried both, restart and total shutdown. No difference. That's actually what made me check if I'd left Fast Boot turned on.

Comment: Fast Boot ≠ Fast Startup. Those are two different things. Fast Startup is the one that needs to be disabled.

Comment: What options did you try, exactly? For all we know, you might have tried the correct solution but implemented it incorrectly.

Comment: Let's see...

This one initially caused the system to lock up at boot, but I dropped out to a command line and fixed the file to point to a directory that exists.

/dev/nvme0n1p3 /media/paul/C ntfs-3g rw,uid=1000,gid-1000,umask-0022,fmask=0022 0 0

My understanding is that it should give read/write access to the ntfs volume to just my userID and group ID, but I still couldn't add anything to any folder on that volume.

I also tried a bare bones approach with:

/dev/nvme0n1p3 /media/paul/C    ntfs defaults 0 0

And a few variations on it, but they all also mounted it as read only.

Comment: Just to confirm, did you do this? -> https://www.windowscentral.com/how-disable-windows-10-fast-startup Not Fast Boot which is a firmware (UEFI) feature and immaterial here. And if you did have you confirmed the settings is still disable? Many Windows updates re-enable it.

Comment: Yeah. I know windows pretty much like the back of my hand. The setting that you inexplicably get to by going through the OS power options. It's disabled. I can post a screen shot, if y'all don't believe me.  Sorry about the formatting in my previous post, by the way. I have no idea how to make it look nicer. I added spacing between lines, but they didn't show up.

Comment: "How to reliably mount a NTFS volume with read/write access"  The only reliable way is to not use them ;-)

Comment: [This link to my answer at Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/713285/copy-paste-not-working-in-ubuntu22/713321#713321) and links from it may help you solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu has nothing to do with that error, actually is how Windows behaves when "turning off". Because theres a huge ammount of computers with HDDs Microsoft had to do something to boot up the OS faster and they solved it by not turning the OS off at all. So how do you turn off Windows? Just by pressing **Restart** instead of **Shut Down** each time you want to use Ubuntu.

Now if you want to be more strict about this
Go to your Control Panel and follow this route `Control Panel\Hardware and Sound\Power Options\System Settings` aka `Choose what the closing lid does`

Go ahead and tell the OS not to do that trick any more.
[image: panel]

Now next time you won't have problems loading that folder.
Also disable Secure Boot that thing messes up linux in general.

Comment: Ok. Can we please stop focusing on the Windows Fast Start feature? I've al;ready confirmed that it's turned off. In fact, I turned it off two years ago in anticipation of this exact problem. It's still turned off, has never been turned back on, and is literally not the cause of my NTFS partition being mounted as read only. I appreciate the advice, but we need to dig deeper.